# Print Array Key => Value

Tags: php

I have an array key => value and I printed it's content:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

and the content is:

```
Array
(
    [restaurants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => The Star
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => restaurant
                            [1] => food
                            [2] => casino
                            [3] => spa
                            [4] => lodging
                            [5] => point_of_interest
                            [6] => establishment
                        )

                    [vicinity] => 80 Pyrmont Street, Pyrmont
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => South Steyne
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => restaurant
                            [1] => food
                            [2] => point_of_interest
                            [3] => establishment
                        )

                    [vicinity] => Harbourside Jetty, Darling Drive, Darling Harbour
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ibis Sydney Darling Harbour
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => restaurant
                            [1] => food
                            [2] => lodging
                            [3] => point_of_interest
                            [4] => establishment
                        )

                    [vicinity] => 70 Murray Street, Pyrmont
                )

            [3] ...
```

I need to print the content's information with this form:

> Name: The Star
>   Type: food, casino, spa, lodging, point_of_interest, establishment
>   Address: 80 Pyrmont Street, Pyrmont

But, when I access to the array with this code:

```
foreach ($result as $value){
    echo "Nome: ".$value["name"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Tipo: ";
    foreach($value->type as $valuearr){
        echo $valuearr["type"].", ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Morada: ".$value["vicinity"];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

the result is:

> Name:
>   Type:
>   Address:

What's the error in the code?

Comment: You really need some php basics.  In particular how to access arrays.  Here's a hint, you cannot use `$value->type` for arrays.

Comment: *"foreach($value->type ... "* -- there is no object (like in ["instance of a class"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)) in your array. There is no place for the `->` construct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the "restaurants" key first, where all the rest is:

```
foreach ($result["restaurants"] as $value){
    // etc.
```

You also have an error at `->type`, because *$result* does not have objects inside, just associative arrays. So change that to:

```
foreach ($result["restaurants"] as $value){
    echo "Nome: ".$value["name"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Tipo: ";
    foreach($value["type"] as $valuearr){
        echo $valuearr.", ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Morada: ".$value["vicinity"];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Finally, that inner loop you can also optimised with using *implode* instead:

```
    echo "Tipo: ";
    echo implode(", ", $value["type"]);
```

Comment: I'm new and noob in stackoverflow, if I gave you a negative vote I'm really sorry. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I hope you will stick around on StackOverflow.